# SQL Query to replace apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `tblReportDescription` that has over a thousand rows of data. In most of these descriptions, there are some words with apostrophes that aren't spaced out probably. For example,
`tests'test` there is no space between `tests'` and `test`. I am attempting to write a query to update the entire table but I do not want to affect the words that are possessive such as `Men's Clothing` or `Women's Clothing` Is there a way to replace an apostrophe without space behind it without affects `'s`?

Here is an example of my table:

| Id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | Tests'Report Title |
| 21 | Tests Reports'Title 2 |
| 3 | Men's Test Report Title 3 |
| 13 | Women's Test Report Title 4 |
| 8 | Test ReportTitle'test |

My expected an outcome would to have a query which updates all `Description` to replace the apostrophe with an apostrophe space that does not affect `'s`

Here is an example of my expected outcome:

| Id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | Tests' Report Title |
| 21 | Tests Reports' Title 2 |
| 3 | Men's Test Report Title 3 |
| 13 | Women's Test Report Title 4 |
| 8 | Test ReportTitle' test |

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE tblReportDescription 
    (
        Id INT,
        Description VARCHAR(100),
    
    )
    
    INSERT INTO tblReportDescription (Id,Description)
    VALUES (34,'Tests'Report Title'),(21,'Tests Reports'Title 2'), (3,'Men's Test Report Title 3'), (13,'Women's Test Report Title 4') , (8,'Test ReportTitle'test') 
    
    
    
UPDATE tblReportDescription
SET Description = (Description, '''', ''' ')
```

I am attempting to say replace a single quote apostrophe with a single quote apostrophe and a space behind it. In this case how could I set it up to not affect `'s` my current code would make `'s` into `' s`

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use regular expression substitution. Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support regular expressions out of the box. You'll need to enable them using an UDF first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the `'` with `'`  and then unreplace the `s '`.  Assuming that your comparisons are case sensitive:

```
update tblReportDescription
    set Description = replace(replace(Description, '''', ''' '), ''' s', '''s')
    where Description like '%''%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=01a5675ecf9bb0c6c8c83b9c51f079fa) is a db<>fiddle showing that it works for all the cases you have specified.  Plus cases where both are mixed together.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with ignoring the entire column if it has `'s`, then you can add a condition that ignores all such rows.

```
UPDATE   tblReportDescription
SET      Description = replace(Description, '''', ''' ')
where    Description not like '%''s%'
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but won't work for mixed cases.